# Hide controller and action in pretty URL with Yii2

Tags: redirect, yii2-advanced-app, pretty-urls

I need to change a URL in Yii2 using the URL Manager from

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?r=tamil-article/articles&categ=Innovation&id=44
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/44/Innovation.html
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by configuring your UrlManager to use prettyUrls.

After that you can add a custom url rule to the rules array (in config/main.php):

```
'urlManager'   => [
    'class'           => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName'  => false,
    // Add the .html suffix 
    'suffix' => '.html',
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules'           => [
        '<id:\d+>/<categ:\w+>' => 'tamil-article/articles',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thank you Szántó Zoltán!!!
Can you please explain how its done. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can match URLs to controllers, actions and parameters. These are located in the rules array where the key is the custom route and the value is the route to the controller and action..